# How to get prediction intervals at mean & at max of covariate values in R

Tags: r, confidence-interval, prediction, prediction-interval

I'm still working on R problems from a book, and using my spending data.

**Part 1:** I need to predict the amount that a male with average data for status, income and verbal would spend along a 95% CI. (NB, male is coded as 0 and female 1 in the data set.)

First I used the linear model `newspend<-lm(sepnding ~ status + income + verbal + sex)` and from a previous question the sex coefficient is for female, so how would I get the male?

```
> qt(0.975,42)
[1] 2.018082
> c(-22.12-2.02*8.21,-22.12+2.02*8.21)
[1] -38.7042  -5.5358
```

*First Question:*  I don't know how what this means and how will I get a 95% CI for males if this is for females?

**Part 2:** Then repeat the prediction for males with maximal values of status, income and verbal and determine which CI is wider. Second, I used the max. values for the data in a new equation.

```
     sex             status          income      
 Min.   :0.0000   Min.   :18.00   Min.   : 0.600  
 1st Qu.:0.0000   1st Qu.:28.00   1st Qu.: 2.000  
 Median :0.0000   Median :43.00   Median : 3.250  
 Mean   :0.4043   Mean   :45.23   Mean   : 4.642  
 3rd Qu.:1.0000   3rd Qu.:61.50   3rd Qu.: 6.210  
 Max.   :1.0000   Max.   :75.00   Max.   :15.000  

     verbal          spending     
 Min.   : 1.00   Min.   :  0.0  
 1st Qu.: 6.00   1st Qu.:  1.1  
 Median : 7.00   Median :  6.0  
 Mean   : 6.66   Mean   : 19.3  
 3rd Qu.: 8.00   3rd Qu.: 19.4  
 Max.   :10.00   Max.   :156.0
```

`x0<-data.frame(status=75.00, income=15.00, verbal=10.00, sex=1.00)`
I'm not sure if this is how I get the maximal values for a male?
(Or should the 2nd part be a new question since it's a lot of information?)

Comment: You have obtained confidence interval not for females (average spending), but for the difference between males and females (with respect to other features in the model).

Comment: so my prediction is incorrect for what I am trying to determine for the problem. Please clarify....thanks

Answer (score 1):

Here is how you set up the date for male average spending estimate with CIs:

```
mavg<-data.frame(status=45.23, income=4.642, verbal=6.66, sex=0.00);
```

...female average:

```
favg<-data.frame(status=45.23, income=4.642, verbal=6.66, sex=1.00);
```

...male max:

```
mmax<-data.frame(status=75.00, income=15.00, verbal=10.00, sex=0.00);
```

...female max:

```
fmax<-data.frame(status=75.00, income=15.00, verbal=10.00, sex=1.00);
```

The general way to get the predictions given a new dataset is...

```
predict(newspend,newdata=FOO,interval='conf');
```

...where `FOO` is whichever one of your new `data.frame`s you want the results for. Or you can combine them into one `data.frame` and get all the results at once:

```
mfavgmax<-rbind(mavg,favg,mmax,fmax);
predict(newspend,newdata=mfavgmax,interval='conf');
```

Be warned though: your model and your predictions assume that status, income, verbal, and sex all affect spending independently of each other. In real life data is rarely that clean. I would check whether there are significant interaction terms:

```
install.packages(MASS); # Only need to run this line once
library(MASS);
newspend.aic<-stepAIC(newspend,trace=F,direction='both',scope=list(lower=.~.,upper=.~(.)^4));
```

Now you can do `predict` on `newspend.aic` like you did above. You might have new interaction terms in the model.

Another problem is that status, income, verbal, and sex may be correlated with *each other* (this is called multicollinearity). So, the population maximum (or average, etc.) for males might be different than for females. At high statuses income mean/max will obviously be different than at lower statuses. For categorical variables like male/female, you can at least get the mean/max for that category and use that for your predictions.

But what if you want to get estimates for spending as status increases continuously form 18 to 75? Sure `predict` will give you estimates with income and verbal set to any number you like... but income and verbal are *not* static, they probably correlated with status and with each other... and how to pick reasonable values for these numeric variables for prediction purposes is the [question that's stumping me right now](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/60864/how-to-algorithmically-find-plausible-covariates-at-which-to-plot-predicted-resp) and how I happened onto your question.

Hope my answer helps, and it's scary, isn't it, how fast you get to the deep end of the pool with a simple-seeming problem?